# How can I select only the columns containing non negative values from a frame using Deedle in C#?

Tags: c#, deedle

I would like to select / filter the columns from a frame that do not contain negative Values. That means creating a new frame with the columns that only contain positive values.

Something like the following (syntax is wrong):

```
var myFrameNoNeg = myFrame.Columns.Where(kvp => kvp.Value > 0); //
```

The idea is to Drop the columns which contain negative values.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting the question - the question is clear (read the first sentence) and it shows what the OP tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pointing in the right direction - you need to use `frame.Columns.Where`. However, this does not give you individual values, but the whole column (as a series) and so you need to (again) iterate over all values in the column:

```
using Deedle;
using System.Linq;

Frame.FromColumns(frame.Columns.Where(kvp => 
  !kvp.Value.As<double>().Values.Any(v => v < 0.0)))
```

Since you are iterating over columns, you need to call `Frame.FromColumns` at the end to turn the series of columns back into a frame.

The `Where` method gives you the column data as boxed series containing objects. Using `As<double>()` is an efficient way to get the values as floating points.